# My F distribution emulation with Monte Carlo method In R does not fit. Why?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, montecarlo

As an exercise, I try to imitate the F distribution of the ratio of two independent variances with the Monte Carlo method in R. But my result occurs significantly larger than it should be. Why?

```
emulateF <- function (numberOfEmulations, sampleSize1, sampleSize2){
ratioVec <- NULL
for (i in 1:numberOfEmulations) {
    sample1 <- rnorm(sampleSize1, mean = 0, sd = 9)
    sample2 <- rnorm(sampleSize2, mean = 0, sd = 9)
    ratio <- var (sample1) / var (sample2)
    if (ratio >= 1) {
        ratioVec <- c(ratioVec, ratio)
    } else {
        ratioVec <- c(ratioVec, 1/ratio)
    }
    }   
return (quantile (ratioVec, 0.975))
}
```

I supposed that the result of this function execution `emulateF (10000, 30, 30)` should be very similar to `qf(0.975,29,29)`. But each time it is about 10% higher. Why?

```
> qf(0.975,29,29)
[1] 2.100996
```

and

```
> for (i in 1:10) {
+ resultsVec <- c (resultsVec, emulateF (10000, 30, 30))
+ }
> resultsVec
   97.5%    97.5%    97.5%    97.5%    97.5%    97.5%    97.5%    97.5% 
2.311599 2.374442 2.377750 2.330585 2.300294 2.359123 2.344875 2.340269 
   97.5%    97.5% 
2.307880 2.350104 
>
```

If I change the `sd = 9` to standard `sd = 1`, the problem remains.

Comment: If you don't get much response here on SO, you might try over at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) where the theme is a bit more mathematically-oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to your code is to remove the `if` statement.  Your `if` statement is forcing every stored value to be greater than 1. That shouldn't be.

FWIW, here's similar code that uses `apply` instead of a `for` loop.

```
myF <- function(n, n1, n2) {
    samp1 <- matrix(rnorm(n1*n, mean=0, sd=9), nrow=n, ncol=n1)
    samp2 <- matrix(rnorm(n2*n, mean=0, sd=9), nrow=n, ncol=n2)
    f <- apply(samp1, 1, var) / apply(samp2, 1, var)
    return(quantile(f, 0.975))
}

set.seed(789)
myF(1e4, 30, 30)
2.09744

qf(0.975, 29, 29)
2.100996
```

Comment: But in real life, we always use a larger variance value as a numerator and a smaller variance as a denominator. Or don't we? Should I choose the numerator and denominator somehow randomly?

Comment: No!  Consider if you had a different number of degrees of freedom instead of 30/30 for your num/denom.  Then occasionally "flipping" the ratio based on whether it's above 1 or not just mixes everything up terribly.  There is no such thing as "the bigger number goes on top".

Comment: Maybe I should always compare p-value to the significance level (0.05) instead of comparing the obtained statistics value to the threshold?

Comment: You can do that, but you should get the same thing.  The "obtained statistic" is the value along the x-axis; the p-value is the area under the curve.  They are two separate measure of the exact same thing.